# Greedy approach correctness

Tags: algorithm, tree, greedy

I'm trying to practice some questions based on greedy algorithms and came across this question:

*In organization ABC, the employees
have an underlying hierarchy, where the CEO is at the top and every other
employee has exactly one manager. An employee can be the manager to one
or more employees. Any employee is familiar with the work of her manager
and the works of her immediate sub-ordinates.
It was decided to give away gift coupons for all employees(including
the CEO) as New year presents. By mistake, the gift coupons ordered
were of three different denominations - 1000, 2000 and 3000. It was
decided that every employee will receive a gift coupon of denomination
different from her manager. However, if an employee receives a gift
coupon of larger denomination than her manager, she is sure to be
given a negative rating by her manager in a fit of jealousy. Design an
algorithm to decide how to distribute gift coupons among employees so
that the number of employees who gets a negative rating is minimized.*

We can represent the organization hierarchy as a tree where every node represents an employee and the CEO is the root.
So far the best approach I could think of was to start at the leaf nodes and assign the lowest denomination denomination (1000) and then Traverse the tree in post-order (bottom-up) and assign gift coupons to each employee.

And then For each employee i that is not a leaf node:
let j be the highest denomination gift coupon assigned to any of i's subordinates. Assign the gift coupon of the next highest denomination that is not assigned to i's manager and is not equal to j. If no such denomination exists, assign the lowest denomination.

Could anyone tell if my approach is correct?

Comment: _"If an employee receives a gift coupon of larger denomination than her manager, she is sure to be given a negative rating by her manager in a fit of jealousy_". Is this applicable only for the direct manager? Or all manager above the employee in the hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. With greedy algorithms though, the difficulty is not in writing the algorithm but in proving that it is correct. Hint: you usually do that by contradiction, i.e. showing that _not_ choosing the locally-optimal decision does _not_ improve the global solution.

Comment: Give everyone 3000. Presumably this isn't a valid solution because you only have a given number of each type of coupon, but forgot to write this constraint down. So, next hint: Consider a tree with a CEO and 2 managers as their subordinates -- one manager having 1 leaf employee below them, and one having 10. A postorder traversal could process either manager's leaves first. What does that tell you?